# How to make maven build failure when bug is found using findBug plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, findbugs

I have just added maven find bug plugin in my project pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>findbugs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

for reporting I have added below:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </plugin>
```

Now when i run maven using **install** it gives me warnings below:

```
> [INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.4:findbugs (default) @
> MovesouqBackend --- [INFO] Fork Value is true
>      [java] Warnings generated: 12 [INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
```

It shows there are 12 bugs as warning and build successful.

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------

----------
```

I want to make build fail when there is any warning found against findbug plugin and I want to show this warning as error.
I have gone through plugin [documentation](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) but there is nothing about it.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your configuration as:

```
<executions>
   <execution>
   <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>findbugs</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <failOnError>true</failOnError>
         <threshold>High</threshold>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: No.It doesn't. When i tried to  <configuration> failOError and threshold it gives me   BUILD SUCCESS. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Worked. when goal changed to  <goal>check</goal>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `check` goal with  tag and set it false not to fail the build.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <effort>Max</effort>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</plugin>
```